# Pull Requests - Ensure linked tasks are closed before allowing PR completion

Tags: azure-devops

We wish to create a workflow where pull requests are only allowed to be completed when all the related tasks are in "done" state to avoid incongruencies.

We know how to block pull requests from being completed unless there is at least one task assigned to it, but we didn't find a way to force Azure DevOps to check the tasks states before allowing said completion.

Right now completing a pull requests sets the related tasks to "done", but we need it to check the state is already "done" before completion, as we want our developers to confirm task completion manually.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> Pull Requests - Ensure linked tasks are closed before allowing PR completion

Indeed, just like you said, the Branch Policies option `Check for linked work items` only check if there is at least one task assigned to it, but not check the tasks states.

And the option `Complete linked work items after merging` is used to completed the work item automatically or not:

[image]

AFAIK, there is no such Branch Policies option or any other setting to check the tasks states, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.